# Gradle won't work with android studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I try to debug an Android app with Android Studio 3.0.1, it generates following error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request. Check logs for details.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request. Check logs for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED in 6s
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Any idea to get rid of that?

The last lines of Gradle console shows following:

```
:app:mergeDebugResources
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request. Check logs for details.
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request. Check logs for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

15 actionable tasks: 14 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

Comment: there can be many reasons for gradle build failure

Comment: try updating your gradle version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurred because I accidentally removed the executable flag from `aapt2` which is located in `$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/27.0.2`.

If you face the same problem try one of the following solutions:

- Re-download the sdk (recommended)
- `sudo chmod 777 -R $ANDROID_HOME`

Note:
`$ANDROID_HOME` is the location where I put android sdk

Answer (score 1):

You may try this :

1. Update the gradle and than,
2. **Go to --> gradle.wrapper.properties**

and replace the distribution Url with this :

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4.1-all.zip
>    You can replace "gradle-3.4.1" with the latest version of gradle for android studio.

3. Make sure your plugins are updated.
4. **While following these steps make sure you have a working internet connection so that gradle as well as the plugins can be updated.**

Hope this helps !

Comment: Did, but no luck